# Realizing a Jacobian as a projective variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/213001/conditions-for-underlying-space-of-an-orbifold-bbb-tn-gamma-to-be-a-sphere/213282#213282) (and my answer thereto). Given an algebraic curve, is there a way to realize its Jacobian explicitly as a zero-set of a bunch of polynomials in $\mathbb{P}^n.$ I care most about the complex case, but all ground fields are of interest...

Answer (score 9):

You might look at Mumford's three articles.

MR0219542 Mumford, D. On the equations defining abelian varieties. III. Invent. Math. 3 1967 215–244.

MR0219541 Mumford, D. On the equations defining abelian varieties. II. Invent. Math. 3 1967 75–135.

MR0204427 Reviewed Mumford, D. On the equations defining abelian varieties. I. Invent. Math. 1 1966 287–354.

There are also articles (David Grant, Victor Flynn, ...) that I think give explicit equations for jacobians of genus 2 curves and explicit equations for the group law.

Comment: Thanks! A particular question is whether these can be hypersurfaces (I think this is not what happens in Greg Anderson's paper...)

Comment: @IgorRivin: do you mean hypersurfaces in projective space? If so, then this only happens for $n=1$ (i.e. elliptic curves in $\mathbf P^2$) by Lefschetz hyperplane theorem.

Comment: @potentiallydense Ah. yes. I was being dense :)

Answer (score 9):

[This paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0001-8708(02)00024-5) by Greg Anderson does just that.

Comment: Pretty cool paper!